If a strong monoidal functor $F$ has an ambidextrous adjoint, then how close is the adjoint to being strong monoidal?
Let $F : C \to D$ be a strong (symmetric, say) monoidal functor. Suppose that $G : D \to C$ is both left and right adjoint to $F$ (an ambidextrous adjunction). Then by doctrinal adjunction $G$ is both lax and oplax monoidal.
Question 1: What kind of compatibility can the lax and oplax monoidal structures on $G$ be chosen to have?
Question 2: For example, under what conditions is $G$ bilax monoidal? Does $G$ preserve bialgebra objects? What about Hopf algebra objects?
Question 3: What if we assume something like $C$ and $D$ have all objects dualizable?
Notes:

Since $G$ is fixed by the choice of one set of adjunction data, the choice of both adjunction data is only well-defined up to non-unique isomorphism. This non-uniqueness translates via doctrinal adjunction to some ambiguity in how the lax and oplax monoidal structures relate. So presumably if you want $G$ to be bilax monoidal you will have to be careful in making this choice, and maybe need to add further assumptions...

I think Proposition 10 here is relevant but I’m a bit confused by the terminology.



Interesting question. Have you looked at examples? A spontaneous idea: Given a Frobenius extension $S\subset R$ of commutative rings, the induction functor $R\otimes_S -$ is a Frobenius functor with a canonical strong monoidal structure. Does its biadjoint, the restriction of scalars/condinduction functor $\operatorname{Mod}(R)\rightarrow \operatorname{Mod}(S)$, preserve Frobenius algebras (resp. bialgebras)? If the answer is negative, it cannot be a Frobenius monoidal (resp. bilax monoidal) functor.
